# Extracting filtered NDVI proportions from polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a dataset with several polygons in which I have to guess the proportion of bared soil. My ideal approach would be to use NDVI data where I select NDVI under, lets say, 0.3, and then calculate the proportion of pixels below that threshold in each of my polygons. A polygon and a NDVI layer would look something like this:[image]

I need the proportion, in %, of pixels in each polygon with NDVI values <0.3.

So far I have this:

```
//

var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection("users/oriolbaena/PositiusEdwEry_2023DIPTA");

Map.centerObject(polygons)
//Define a geometry.
Map.addLayer(polygons);


// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2020-12-01', '2023-06-01')
  .filterBounds(polygons)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
  var QA10 = image.select(['QA10']); 
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1))
};


//

// Define an index function (return only NDVI).
var NDVI = function (image){
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']
  ).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the NDVI transformation.
 .map(NDVI);
```

At this point I would need to select only the pixel values I need and then calculate the proportions in %. I really only need one value for each polygon in which I have the % of bare soil each polygon has for that period!

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have data for multiple years - each location will have a number of NDVI values, one for every 5 day or so. You didn't specify how you want to turn this time-series of NDVI values into a single value. In the below script I assume you want the median NDVI over time.

When you want to aggregate all pixel values inside a single geometry, you use `reduceRegion()`, when you have multiple you can use `reduceRegions()`. You didn't share your asset with polygons, but it sounds like you got more than one.

```
var medianNdvi = S2
  .map(maskcloud1)
  .map(NDVI)
  .median() // Reduce the collection to a single image, taking the median over time

var aboveTreshold = medianNdvi.gt(0.3) // Each pixels is 0 or 1

var percentageAboveThreshold = aboveTreshold
  .multiply(100) // Each pixel is 0 or 100
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: polygons, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), // Mean will give you the percentage
    scale: 10, 
    // tileScale: 16 // If you run out of memory, enable this
  })

print(percentageAboveThreshold)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6beb63ce20e3240f6b3abefe8be238fb

You mixed up the `QA10` and the `QA60` bands in your script. It is `QA60` you want to use. Well, actually - `QA60` is not a very good way to mask clouds. If you run into problems with clouds, you should read up on `COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY` and the newer and even better `GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED` cloud mask collections. Though the full back-catalog of scenes has not been processed for the latter one yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! Really mindblowing. Just a couple of things. I mentioned that I want NDVI values lower than 0.3 and in your script you are using the function `.gt`and the words above. It should be `.lt`and below, don't be? Another element is the masking of the clouds. In my script I was using 2 elements `.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);` and the `masking function` with `QA60`. What would be your approach using `COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY`? Using that param in `.filterMetadata`, creating a masking function? Both? Thanks again!!

Comment: The `collection.filter*()` functions exclude whole images from your collection. The more you remove up front, the faster your processing. If you want to filter on clouds depends on your area. In really cloudy areas, you might have to include cloudy scenes and extract the few cloud free pixels there are, in order to get a composite without masked pixels. Here's your script using the cloud probability collection: https://code.earthengine.google.com/85a119a2623acbf2991464b11940883f

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel!